# can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str error

Tags: python-3.x

I am making a ROBLOX account checker using robloxpy. (Python 3.x)
And when i execute the code it gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Korisnik\Desktop\project\project.py", line 16, in <module>
    print("\nRAP: " + RapFetch)
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str
```

Here is the code:

```
import robloxpy
import time

UserID = input("Enter your ROBLOX ID: ")

NameFetch = robloxpy.GetName(UserID)
RapFetch = robloxpy.GetUserRAP(UserID)
LimitedValueFetch = robloxpy.GetUserLimitedValue(UserID)
FollowerFetch = robloxpy.GetFollowersCount(UserID)
FollowingFetch = robloxpy.GetFollowingCount(UserID)
BannedFetch = robloxpy.IsBanned(UserID)
AccountAgeFetch = robloxpy.AccountAgeDays(UserID)

print("\nUsername: " + NameFetch)
time.sleep(0.1)
print("\nRAP: " + RapFetch)
time.sleep(0.1)
print("\nLimited Value: " + LimitedValueFetch)
time.sleep(0.1)
print("\nFollowers: " + FollowerFetch)
time.sleep(0.1)
print("\nFollowing: " + FollowingFetch)
time.sleep(0.1)
print("\nBanned: " + BannedFetch)
time.sleep(0.1)
print("\nAccount Age (In Days): " + AccountAgeFetch)

input("\nPress ENTER to exit console")
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is some players just don't have a RAP (recent average price) attribute so it returns `None` -- either you can replace this by a `''` or `'0'`:

```
RapFetch = robloxpy.GetUserRAP(UserID) or ''
```

or you can just straight out print out the `None`:

```
print(f"\nRAP: {RapFetch}")
```

Might have to apply this to the other attributes as well.

Comment: Well I tried it on a player that has RAP, but it still gave this error.

Comment: @IAmADumDum Okay. Try upgrading to the most recent version of the library, if that still doesn't work, ask the library maintainer or post another question (include a user id that has a RAP for verification)